# "Really" disable entire cache during development (also routing, twig templates, css+js libraries)

Tags: 8, caching

I have followed the community documentation page at https://www.drupal.org/node/2598914 (Disable Drupal 8 caching during development). Now I expect that the caching in my Drupal 8 site is entirely switched off. However, for setting up an new route, a twig template or any css/js library in mymodule/mymodule.libraries.yml, I still need to run

```
drush cr
```

to get my stuff recognized by Drupal 8. How can I "fully" disable caching? It is annoying to run "drush cr" dozens of times and repeatedly guess if the specific item is either cached or not..

Answer (score 1):

I asked this on twitter and [@renebakx](https://twitter.com/renebakx) replied:

> [@stevepurkiss](https://twitter.com/stevepurkiss) check how devel modules handles this, it worked for
>   templates and added css/js to the theme's library. Not for added
>   routes

[image: theme registry]